# Ruby Could not find mime-types-data-3.2016.0221 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby, bundler, phusion

I'm trying to get Ruby up and running but keep running into this problem. 
OS: Debian 6 Wheezy
Ruby: 2.2.1
Rails: 4.2.6

Create a new project:
Rails new Sample1

Get the famous "We're sorry page", 
error page:
**Could not find mime-types-data-3.2016.0221 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)**
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:94:in `block in materialize'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in`map!'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `materialize'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:137:in`specs'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:182:in `specs_for'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:171:in`requested_specs'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in`setup'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:92:in `setup'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in`'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in`block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in`run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in`'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in`'

I've been trying all day to get this going. I had no idea Ruby would be so tough just to get up and running.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this issue myself. [As have others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202822/ruby-rails-installation-and-configuration-issues).

You could try installing the gem directly:

```
gem install mime-types-data -v '3.2016.0221'
```

Then trying running Phusion Passenger again. If there is a similar error for another gem, it might mean that the gems were installed in a different location than Phusion Passenger is using.

For example, you might also need to install a newer version of `mime-types`:

```
gem install mime-types -v '3.0'
```

I don't have much experience with Phusion Passenger. Does it work with [RVM](https://rvm.io/)? It might be worth using RVM if that is possible.

Comment: Got the same error, manually installing `mime-types-data` and `mime-types` with the latest versions fixed the issue. However, I had to run [`bundle clean --force`](https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-clean.1.html) first.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bundle install` to make sure all dependencies are installed.

I got a similar error when running a dockerized ruby app locally - I forgot to re-build the app after adding new gems to the Gemfile.